# If the graph over a disc in $\Bbb{R}^2$ of radius $r$ has mean curvature $H \geq a$, then $ar \leq 1$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

The following is Exercise (18) at the end of Chapter 3 in *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd edition, by Montiel and Ros:

> Let $S$ be the graph over a disc in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with radius $r > 0$. If $S$ has mean curvature $H \geq a$ at each point for some real number $a$, show that $ar \leq 1$.

The execise is solved at the end of the chapter, but I did not quite get it. The solution provided is as follows:

> If $a \leq 0$ the result is obvious. Assume $a > 0$. Take $0 < R < r$ and let $\Bbb{S}_R^2$ be a sphere with radius $R$ that has constant mean curvature $1/R$ with respect to its inner normal. Assume that $S$ is a graph over a disc centered at the origin of the plane $z = 0$. Drop the sphere $\Bbb{S}_R^2$ onto $S$ in the two possible ways and obtain, using exercise (20) at the end of Chapter 2, two points of tangency between $S$ and $\Bbb{S}_R^2$. At least at one of them, say $p$, the normal of $S$ coincides with the inner normal of $\Bbb{S}_R^2$ Now use exercise (17) to obtain 
>   $$
> a \leq H(p) \leq 1/R.
> $$
>   Then $aR \leq 1$ for all $R < r$.

My questions are:

> What do the authors mean by "Drop the sphere $\Bbb{S}_R^2$ onto $S$ in the two possible ways"? Which ways are these?

Below are the statements of Exercises (20) of Chapter 2 and (17):

> (20): Suppose two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ cut it other transversely at a point $p \in T_pS_1 \cap T_pS_2$. Prove that if $t \in \Bbb{R}$ is small enough then $\phi_t(S_1) \cap S_2 \neq \emptyset$ where $\phi_t$ is the translation of $\Bbb{R}^3$ given by $\phi_t(p) = p + ta$ where $a \in \Bbb{R}^3$ with $|a| = 1$.
>
> (17) Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two orientable surfaces that are tangent in a common point $p \in S_1 \cap S_2$ and let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be the corresponding Gauss maps such that $N_1(p) = N_2(p)$. We express $S_1$ and $S_2$ near the point $p$ as two graphs of functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ defined on the common tangent plane. We say that $S_1$ is over $S_2$ at $p$ if there exists a neighborhood of the origin of this plane where $f_1 \geq f_2$. Prove that if $S_1$ is over $S_2$ at $p$ then $\sigma_1(v, v) \geq \sigma_2(v, v)$ for each $v \in T_pS_1 = T_pS_2$. In particular, $H_1(p) \geq H_2(p)$. Show that if $\sigma_1(v, v) > \sigma_2(v, v)$ for each $v \neq 0$ then $S_1$ is over $S_2$ at $p$.

$\sigma$ denotes the second fundamental form.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: They mean to "drop" the sphere from above and from below, so that the sphere contacts $S$ tangentially in either case. The reference to exercise (20) makes no sense to me.

Comment: Dear Ted, thank you very much for your comment. And this "drop" is with the center of the sphere moving along the $z$ axis?

Comment: Parallel to it, yes. Gravity is still presumed vertical. :)

Comment: But if not exactly along the z axis, we will have a number of ways the surfaces are tangent? It does not matter?

Comment: You're looking for the low (high from underneath) point on the surface. It's how highly unlikely that it lies over the origin.

Comment: Oh, I think now I understand: we are taking all spheres with radius $< r$ and dropping it in every possible way, to obtain tangency points all over the surface $S$, is that correct? Just one detail. Suppose $S$ to be concave, like a mountain. Then the sphere would roll out along the sides of the mountain. Are we supposing some "walls" over the boundary of the disc?